# How to use dplyr to group by column and then add another more

Tags: r, dplyr, sentiment-analysis

I have recently started training myself into sentiment analysis.I have a dataset that looks like this:[initial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYhV6.png)

The original data consisted of reviews of wines, one per each row. What I have done is tokenize it and performed basic sentiment analysis with one of the R lexicons. As can bee seen in the screentshot. Column X refers to the original row in the initial data frame. What I want to do now is calculate the net effect( to see which is the prevailing for each row- positive or negative, however in numbers for each original row(X) and attach it as a column).
I have tried with the following code but it does not work:

```
per_row <- unigrams_all_ns %>%
inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"),by=c("unigram"="word"))%>%
group_by(X)%>%
spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0)
```

I get the following error

Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a function

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I think you shall first summarise and then spread
    `group_by(X, sentiment) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: I am a bit confused with your statement. Do you mean you want to know how many positive and negative words exist for each level of X? If so, `count(X, sentiment)` would follow `inner_join()` in your code. If you wanna have a wide-format data, you would  use `spread(key = sentiment, value = n, fill = 0)` after the `count()`.

Comment: @Vova Thanks that worked like a charm.

Comment: @jazzurro yes I want to know how many positives and how many negatives are for a level of x. And afterwards I will calculate the net - either positive if #possitves>#negatives and so on.

Comment: @Pesho OK. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to count how many positive and negative words exist for each group in `X`. You can use `count()` in the dplyr package. It seems that you want to have a wide-format data given what you tried to do. So I used `spread()`. I think you can do more from here by yourself.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)

unigrams_all_ns <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                              unigram = c("smooth", "snappy", "dominate", "crisp", "stainless", "lemon", 
                                          "blossom", "opulent", "rough", "pleasantly"),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

unigrams_all_ns %>%
inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"), by =c("unigram" = "word"))%>%
count(X, sentiment) %>%
spread(key = sentiment, value = n, fill = 0)

      X negative positive
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  1.00     0        1.00
2  2.00     0        4.00
3  3.00     1.00     2.00
4  4.00     1.00     1.00
```